# How to set password based authentication with dropbear ssh in linux

Tags: linux, dropbear

I know that dropbear allows to set public key based authentication. But I want to set up password based authentication not the key based one. I have tried not to put "-s" flag on DROPBEAR_OPTIONS variable. but it still showing me public key denied message.

Comment: What is the relation to SO?

Comment: For the existing key based method, we have to copy rsa public key of every machine from which we want to remotely unlock that luks encrypted PC. but with password based authentication we don't have to do so.